# Silverstripe currentUser()->DateFormat

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm wondering how to use Member::currentUser()->DateFormat to format a date from a model into a string. My use case is in a GridField column with the object title prepended:

`return $this->Title . " (" . $this->Date . ")";`

I'd like the GridField string to use the date format chosen by the CMS user.

I've tried:

`return $this->Title . " (" . date(Member::currentUser()->DateFormat, $this->Date) . ")";`

But because the CMS stores the users date in a different format than PHP's date format, it returns some wonky results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a helper method on `Date`, exactly for that purpose, [`Date->FormatFromSettings`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.6/source-class-Date.html#163-183).

If your DataObject has a field called `Date`, you can use something like this to format the date to a string (based on current member settings):

```
$this->dbObject('Date')->FormatFromSettings()
```

In a template, you should be able to use:

```
$Date.FormatFromSettings
```

And if you just want to format the date in a GridField, it might be enough to specify the `summary_fields` of your DataObject, such as:

```
private static $summary_fields = [
    'Title' => 'Title',
    'Date.FormatFromSettings' => 'Date'
];
```

Using this in a CMS context is not a problem. When using this for Frontend code, you'd have to consider the case where there's no member logged in. In these cases `FormatFromSettings` will return `false`… So you might have to write your own getter for the date, that will return the user-formatted date when somebody is logged in, and a fallback formatting for the other cases.

Comment: Amazing! FormatFromSettings() is exactly what I needed. I couldn't use the summary_fields way because I needed to prepend the title, but this worked perfectly.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with a Time datatype?

Comment: @Chris you can look at the `FormatFromSettings` implementation in `SS_Datetime`, I guess you'd have to extract the part that only formats the time from there

Comment: looking into that, it seems like it'll be a bit messy. Unless you know of a way to do it cleanly. Otherwise, would it be worth a PR to add FormatFromSettings to the Time datatype?

Comment: Yeah, a PR would certainly be a good idea. Or you could write an extension that adds the desired functionality to the `Time` DBField.

Comment: That's what I've done in the meantime, I'll put together a PR to add FormatFromSettings() to the Time datatype. Thanks dude!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure $this->Date is a timestamp value and not a formatted date / datetime value.

Comment: I've tried with both 'Date' and 'SS_Datetime' datatypes and getting the same results